# Отображение и проверка captcha

Tags: c#, captcha

Спрашивал у гугла сабж, не нашел нормального объяснения даже на английском. Объясните, как отображать капчу и проверять с помощью C#?

Comment: [ReCaptcha with Asp.Net MVC](http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Вопрос задан не очень понятно. Вам нужно брать капчу с сайта, или же генерировать в самой программе?

Comment: Брать капчу с сайта, т.е имеется captcha_key. Как реализовать интерфейс вывода капчи в программе.

Comment: Есть предложения еще?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете реализовать свою капчу. Простой генератор изображений + генератор чисел или слов.  Каждый из символом выводить в некотором интервале случайного угла. Реализацию на С# вам, к сожалению, не приведу.